# CentOS 8 not installing in virtualBox.Takes me to installation window after reboot

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I have **VirtualBox 6.1**. I am trying to install **CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1**.
I created a virtual machine with below specs :

**Memory** : 8 GB

**Storage** : 50 GB

I then tried to create a VDI. After the iso was loaded, I could see the installation page come up with below options :

**1).Install Centos 8**

**2).Test this media and install Centos 8**

I chose second option i.e. Test and install.
I proceeded with the installation process and finally the screen said **"CentOS is now successfully installed and ready for you to use. Go ahead and reboot to start using it"**.

After I click on the **reboot** button, it displays **terminated** on screen only for a fraction of a second and then it takes me back to the first installation page where it provides two options of installataion as above.

I have tried several times but no luck.

Not sure whats the issue. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you unmount the installation media?

Comment: @rage Unmounting means removing from Virtual Media Manager, right ? I removed iso image from optical disk section everytime and deleted the created VM each time 
 and then created the machine and installed. Tried this several times. didn't work. Let me know if I understood your question well

Comment: Note: During the complete process of installation, I didn't change any of the settings, or remove the iso. When installation was complete and even after rebooting, I again got to the installation page ,then only I tried to remove everything and install from scratch.

Comment: What happens if you _only_ remove the ISO from the virtual drive (storage section of your VM, not the Virtual Media Manager) and start your VM? Does it boot?

Comment: removing iso from listing Controller : IDE in the storage section of VDI settings?

Comment: @Freddy I just tried removing the iso, and started my VM. it does start.

Comment: But is my installation fine? any chance of getting it corrupted ?

Comment: Well done! Removing the ISO from the Virtual Media Manager would work too, but this is not necessary as other machines could use this ISO too. I guess you'll see it soon enough if your installation is corrupted. Please write a short [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thank you!

Comment: I'm having issues installing GuestAdditions. getting error while trying to insert guest addition image : Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

Answer (score 2):

As Freddy suggested, removing the ISO image from **Controller : IDE** in the **Storage** section of the virtual machine settings and then starting the VM resolved the issue. CentOS started successfully.

However, I ran into the issue of not being able to install the guest additions.
I will update as soon as I'm able to get around this.